# How To Append Products To A Cart Using The Shopify API?

Tags: rest, shopify, e-commerce, shopify-api

I have the cart token, and I'm trying to append products to the cart using the Shopify API. However, when making the following cURL request, I'm getting a "Bad Request" error:

```
curl --location 'https://dev-dotkonnekt.myshopify.com/admin/api/2023-04/carts/b6822c166dd8d044/items.json' \
--header 'X-Shopify-Access-Token: token' \
--header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
--data '{
  "variant_id": 41182214520876,
  "quantity": 1
}'
```

I'm using the correct cart token and the variant ID. Can someone please suggest what might be causing this error? Additionally, if there are any alternative APIs or methods available to achieve the same result, I would greatly appreciate any suggestions.

Thank you in advance for your help!

Trying the above curl request throws a "Bad Request Error".
How can I append a product to cart using the cart ID in Shopify?